# Is there a specific name for these graphics?

Tags: design, web, graphics

I have been tumbling the internet for some time now. I cannot do web design even to save my life, and I was thinking to change that. I have seen a lot of these simply looking web graphics, that seems to be really modern now a days. Robby's website demonstrates them really well.

http://www.rleonardi.com/

I want to look more into them and find some tutorials, however when i google something like "simple web graphics tutorial". It is obviously not what comes up.

**Is there a specific name for these kind of graphics?**

Comment: Hey Jonas, It would be good if you can attach an image/screenshot of the graphics you refer to, in case the link does not exist in the future. Use the image icon to attach images. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try; "character cartoon illustrations", "cartoon illustrations", "simple cartoon illustrations" and similiar

[image]ack.imgur.com/PZgeM.png

Answer (score -1):

Those 'simple illustrations' are often referred to as 'flat design style illustrations' defined pro's and con's:
[image: https://www.interaction-design.org/literature/topics/flat-design]

Comment: Please don't paste images of text ... paste the text itself. Also, you should cite where the text came from.